# python: Is there a stronger version of json other than the built in one

Tags: python, json

I use the built in `json` for python 2.6. I'm having tons of trouble parsing jsons like this:

```
{
 name: 'some name'
 value: 'some value'
}
```

I found two reasons -

1. `'` doesn't work. You need `"`
2. the keys of the dictionary need to be strings. I.e `"name"`/`"value"`

Am I missing something? Is there a way to parse this kind of dictionary using the `json` package? Is there any other python package that can parse this?

Thanks

Comment: According to this (http://json.org/) what you have is not JSON in the first place.  Where did you get it?

Comment: S.Lott is right that this clearly isn't JSON.  If you add a comma between entries, it's a JavaScript literal.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735801/convert-google-results-object-pure-js-to-python-object) is similar, and the accepted answer (demjson) will parse it after you add the comma.

Comment: I got it from selenium's `captureNetworkTraffic`. According to them it's json.

Comment: Tip: if they can screw up JSON this badly, there probably isn't much they *can* do right.

Comment: Your task, then, is to ask them how it squares with the standard described on http://json.org.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that what you want is not a "stronger" parser but a broken parser that will parse broken code. See [the standard](http://www.json.org/)

specifically,

- The keys of an object are defined to be strings
- Strings are defined to be "" or "chars" where chars has the pretty much obvious meaning

There's someplace on the internet where you can watch Douglass Crockford make semi-witty remarks about why this is the case. It has to do with compatibility with non-javascript languages though. Specifically, you could not have

```
{name :'some name', value: 'some value'}
```

as a dict in python unless `name` and `some value` where preexisting, hashable variables;

Broken parsers in general are bad. Just look at the mess that broken HTML parsers in browsers have created where any idiot can make a web site. That dude that wrote all those RFC's had it wrong: It's better to be strict in what you emit **and** what you accept.

Comment: Completely agree - just look at the mess created by non-compliant HTML being accepted by web browsers! Now you have to work ten times as hard to get one simple page display the same across browsers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with the Python module, the problem is with your string, which could be whatever you say, but not JSON, so it cannot be parsed by a JSON parser.

If it were JSON it would look like:

```
{"name":"some name", "value":"some value"}
```

So, it is not a problem with the Python module. It is like asking for a "stronger python compiler" because C-Python cannot parse:

```
using json
json.loads(my_string)
```

Obviously the first line is simply **not Python**, so we cannot ask Python to interpret it.

Now if you want to parse that string I recommend that you either: make it a JSON string OR use [Pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) for writing a quick and dirty parser (I guarantee it will work great in less than, say, 50 lines).

Cheers,

Juan.

Answer (score 0):

There are:

- [simplejson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/), which is "is the externally maintained development version of the json library included with Python 2.6 and Python 3.0, but maintains backwards compatibility with Python 2.5."
- [cjson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-cjson)

(Not sure if they'll parse broken JSON.)