# converting string to list

Tags: python

How to convert string to list

```
str = '[(testing1@testing.com, amit, laspal,1,100,50), 
        (testing2@testing.com,None,None,None,None,None), 
        (testing3@testing.com,laspal, amit,None,None,None)]'
```

I want to get tuple inside the list.
so my new list will be:

```
list =[(testing1@testing.com, amit, laspal,1,100,50),
       (testing2@testing.com,None,None,None,None,None), 
       (testing3@testing.com,laspal, amit,None,None,None)]
```

I can user `eval(string)` but that does not work for my case.

Thanks.

Comment: The string is way too close to Python or JSON for not to be it, yet it isn't. I'm guessing you are doing something simple, but in a very complex way. Possibly it would be better for you to ask how to solve your actual problem, with code examples of what you are doing, instead of just asking for help with the specific problem that's you are struggling with now. It sounds like you are trying to solve an issue the wrong way.
Also, your desired result is a syntax error, so that's clearly not what you desire at all.

Comment: Oh ok. I got the point. the string I was getting was not in my hand. after changing the string I can use ast.literal_eval(string) for my purpose.

Comment: And don't assign values to builtins such as str and list.

Comment: "the string I was getting was not in my hand"... If you are planning to use `eval()`, make sure you know where the input is coming from, and how it's generated. If your program is reading input from an external source, maybe produced by an user, it could be a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, use regular expressions.

```
import re
p = re.compile('(([\w@]+),(\w+),(\w+),(\d+),(\d+))')
f = p.finditer("yourstring")
result = []
for e in f:
    result.append(e.groups()[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved a similar one [a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735801/convert-google-results-object-pure-js-to-python-object/2735870#2735870), but the question isn't *quite* a duplicate. You might want to work `ast.literal_eval()` in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
str = '[(testing1@testing.com, amit, laspal,1,100,50), (testing2@testing.com,None,None,None,None,None), (testing3@testing.com,laspal, amit,None,None,None)]'
list = [str]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).